# Change browser URL using JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, url

I've tried to implement a menu bar which doesn't reload the page but modify the url in the browser and also display the data using ajax.
Somehow using **HTML5 history api** i've achieved this:

http://tinywall.info/demos/html5-history-api/menu1.php

When i checked this in **IE9**, it is reloading the page. As i googled, it was specified IE9- doesn't support html5 history api. But when i tried **Google Plus** in IE9, the navigation menu is getting the ajax content as well as changing the url. Is there any other concept to achieve this??..

Answer (score 2):

Google Plus is probably using `location.hash` and [`onhashchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of changing the full URL.

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 objects , attributes are not yet draft yet, it is scheduled to get its final version till 2024 and first draft at the end of 2012 .

Browser compatibility is the common issue in HTML5 you can add the attributes to the page by using the js, but object behavior depend on the browser itself so you have to wait for the newer version of ie (compatible one J). As per now there is no workaround